# ngIF false value ignored at runtime

Tags: angular

My *ngIf directive is being honored for bringing an element into the DOM, but not out of it.  Using the code below, I can successfully call showGlobalDialog() from the Parent Component, but hideGlobalDialog() doesn't seem to work.

Child Component Template:

```
<div class="modal" *ngIf="isVisible === true">
     <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Child Component:

```
public show(): void {
    this.isVisible = true;
}

public hide(): void {
    this.isVisible = false;
}
```

Parent Component Template:

```
<app-mycomponent #globalDialog>
    <div>
        <button (click)="hideGlobalDialog()">Done</button>
    </div>
</app-mycomponent>
```

Parent Component:

```
@ViewChild('globalDialog') globalDialog: MyComponent;

    private showGlobalDialog() {
        this.globalDialog.show();
    }

    public hideGlobalDialog() {
        this.globalDialog.hide();
    }
```

Oddly enough, the DOM explorer in both Edge and Chrome show that the ngIf is correctly set to false:

on showGlobalDialog():

```
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}-->
```

on hideGlobalDialog():

```
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
```

However, even with the above bindings comment, the elements are still visible.  I don't want the element to exist in the DOM when 'isVisible' is false, so moving to [hidden] isn't an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reboot of the web server ended up fixing the problem, and everything worked fine.